# Add functionality to a website inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, onload

I need to Access the `<head>` element inside an iframe an write something into it, giving the Website loaded into the iframe more functionality.

This works:

```
function dosomething() {
    var target = $(frames["iFrame"].window.document).contents().find("head")[0];
    ...
    target.appendChild(someChild);
}
something.onclick = dosomething();
```

But i want to add the functionality instantly after the page inside the iframe is loaded, everytime a new page is loaded into it.

```
document.getElementById('iFrame').onload = function() {
    var target = $(frames["iFrame"].window.document).contents().find("head")[0];
}();
```

This gives me an Error in 2. line "Cannot read property 'window' of undefined"

```
var iFrame = document.getElementById('iFrame');
iFrame.addEventListener('onload', function() {
function refresh() {
    var target = $(frames["iFrame"].window.document).contents().find("head")[0];
    ...
    target.appendChild(someChild);
});
```

"Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference"

```
$( '#iFrame' ).on( "load", function() {
    var target = $(frames["iFrame"].window.document).contents().find("head")[0];
    ...
    target.appendChild(someChild);
});
```

Here it doesn't throw any error, but also doesn't step into the function.
This seems all very strange to me. What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain as the parent window? If not, you'll be blocked by the browser XSS security

Comment: You can't: [XSS protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: Both are local files. Why does it work in first example then?